# Delete records in axapta very slow

Tags: axapta, record, delete-record

I've got a form in ax 2009, showing filtered records of a table (about 5.000.000 records total, about 1000 shown filtered).
Selecting a couple of those records in the form and deleting them via form-control (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd>) is very slow. 
One record is deleted immediately, selecting about 20 takes several minutes!
There is only one deleteAction on the table - any idea what could thwart the operation?

> edit:

The regarding table has two indices, both don't allow duplicates. First one is an index on an integer field, second one is a combined one of three fields.

createRedIdIndex is not activated.

The filter makes use of one column ( employeeID ) in a queryBuildRange.

deleteAction: another table (B) references the id ( indexed ) of the mentioned table (A). A has a deleteAction on B. setting is "cascade"

The two tables are related via id-field.

The relations can be resolved by an index.

And it's only an amount of about 20 records I want to delete - so I don't go in line with the idea, that the "to-delete-data-amount" is too big!

Comment: Describe your index. Is the index unique? Is RecIdIndex enabled?
Describe your filter. Is your filter resolved by an index? 
Describe your deleteAction. Is the tables related? Can the relation be resolved by an index?

Comment: The items will be removed in a transaction, maybe the amount of data you are removing is too big.

Comment: updated information in original-post

Comment: The filter makes use of one column (employeeID): are there an index with employeeId as the first field?

Comment: The proper AX name for employeeID would be EmplId (provided it is linked to EmplTable).

Comment: You mention you have used SQL tracing and the `DELETE` queries look okay *to you*. Can you post these as an update please? Also, take a look at the [query execution plan](http://dynamicsaxcloud.blogspot.de/2012/12/analyzing-sql-execution-plans-in-sql.html) of one of these queries

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look on this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140429033326/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2010/07/12/forms-with-a-high-number-of-records-take-a-significant-time-to-show.aspx).

Consider adding

```
grid.autoSizeColumns(false);
```

as suggested in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Do diagnose database performance issues in AX, enable SQL tracing in Tools\Setup in the SQL tab page.

Comment: done this - everything seems ok. no warnings, queries ok.
but execution time still is too long.
it takes about several minutes to delete 100 entries.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code profiler to see where the time is used.